# Showing UIDocument controls below appodeal banner in Unity

Tags: unity

I use Unity engine for my app.

In one of my scenes I have a single UIDocument, with a root VisualElement containing a few buttons and that buttons aligned to the bottom of it's parent VisualElement container.

Next - I show Appodeal banner at the top of my scene.

The problem is Appodeal banner show itself over my controls in uidocument.

So I want to resize my root VisualElement, containing buttons to place that buttons below Appodeal banner (i.e. AppodealBannerHeight + ButtonsHeight = HeightThatINeed).

I get height for Appodeal banner in onLoaded banner callback.

And I get buttons height via something like myButton.resolvedStyle.height.

But it doesn't work as expected - calculated position is different for landscape and portrait screen orientation and also that position differs for different screen resolutions.

I think I miss something simple.
How I can resolve that issue?